# clearInterval is not clearing

Tags: javascript, scope, clearinterval

Take a look at the function below, It purpose is to change the button text 
to "Abort", "Abort 0", "Abort 1" and so on.

Once the counter reaches 10 another function should be executed, but if
the button is clicked, the counter should stop, and the button text should return 
to it's original value ("Sync DB").

It seems I'm trying to clear out the interval in a wrong way.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
function sync_database(abort)
{
if (abort == true) { sync_db_btn.innerHTML = "Sync DB"; return false }

sync_db_btn.innerHTML = "Abort"
var i = 0;
sync_db_btn.addEventListener("click", function() { sync_database(true) } );

var x = setInterval(function() {
    if (abort == true) {
        clearInterval(x);
    }

    if (i < 10) {
        sync_db_btn.innerHTML = "Abort " + i++; 
    }
}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: When you call `sync_database` the first time, I assume you're passing `false` or some falsey value to the `abort` parameter. That's the value that the `setInterval` callback is reading. It doesn't have access to the `true` value passed when the button is clicked.

Comment: And a solution for that is? Passing the abort to the setInterval function?

Comment: Any variable that you want shared between calls should be placed outside the function. So if you created a variable outside called `var aborting`, and then inside did `aborting = abort`, and tested `if (aborting == true) {` in the `setInterval`, that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
var sync_db_btn = document.getElementById('but'),
    abortSync = -1,
    interval,
    sync_database = function () {
        var i = 0;
        abortSync *= -1;
        if (abortSync < 0) {
            sync_db_btn.innerHTML = 'Sync DB';
            clearInterval(interval);
            return false;
        }
        sync_db_btn.innerHTML = 'Abort';
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            if (i < 10) {
                sync_db_btn.innerHTML = 'Abort ' + i++;
            } else {
                sync_db_btn.innerHTML = 'Sync DB';
                clearInterval(interval);
                abortSync = -1;
            }
        }, 1000);
    };
sync_db_btn.addEventListener('click', sync_database);
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yw5ut/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var x;

sync_db_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    sync_database(true); 
    clearInterval(x); 
} );

function sync_database(abort)
{
if (abort == true) { sync_db_btn.innerHTML = "Sync DB"; return false }

    sync_db_btn.innerHTML = "Abort"
    var i = 0;

    x = setInterval(function() {    
        if (i < 10) {
            sync_db_btn.innerHTML = "Abort " + i++; 
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: +1 Good idea to take this approach, and move the click handler outside the `sync_database` function.

Comment: I would give serious consideration to renaming that global variable to something other than x

Comment: I would also recommend to separate this into 2 functions. `sync_database` and `abort_sync` instead of having this condition in the same function but that is up to the OP to decide

Comment: @php_nub_qq Looks like this snippet won't work, it executes `sync_database()` once, then clears the newly set interval...